# Ugly sudo password prompt inside of my script output

Tags: bash, ubuntu

I'm writing a simple script to automate editing crontabs on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. I need a section of my code to display the current crontabs on the system.

I currently have this:

```
for user in $cut -d ':' -f 1 /etc/passwd | sed -n '35,60000p'); do echo $user; sudo crontab -u $user; done
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^    ^^^^          ^^^^
Getting a list of non-system users                      Displaying user         Displaying the crontab of each user.
```

However, when I execute the command, I sometimes get an output that inserts the sudo password prompt after the first username in the list, resulting in a very ugly and hard-to-read report.

Could someone help me resolve this issue? I would like to have it so that it prompts you for the superuser password before it displays the report.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right before your `for`-loop, add this command:

```
sudo -v
```

That will update cached `sudo` credentials, prompting for a password if necessary, but otherwise have no effect. (For details, search for `--validate` in [the Sudo Manual](http://www.sudo.ws/man/sudo.man.html).)

Better yet, you might want to abort the script if that fails:

```
sudo -v || exit $?
```